# Want to get part of string using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, string, url

I have a string:

```
 <a class="x3-large" href="_ylt=Ats3LonepB5YtO8vbPyjYAWbvZx4;_ylu=X3oDMTVlanQ4dDV1BGEDMTIwOTI4IG5ld3MgZGFkIHNob290cyBzb24gdARjY29kZQNwemJ1ZmNhaDUEY3BvcwMxBGVkAzEEZwNpZC0yNjcyMDgwBGludGwDdXMEaXRjAzAEbWNvZGUDcHpidWFsbGNhaDUEbXBvcwMxBHBrZ3QDMQRwa2d2AzI1BHBvcwMyBHNlYwN0ZC1mZWEEc2xrA3RpdGxlBHRlc3QDNzAxBHdvZQMxMjc1ODg0Nw--/SIG=12uht5d19/EXP=1348942343/**http%3A//news.yahoo.com/conn-man-kills-masked-teen-learns-son-063653076.html"  style="font-family: inherit;">Man kills masked teen, learns it&#39;s his son</a>
```

And I want to get only the last part of it, the actual message:

```
Man kills masked teen, learns it&#39;s his son
```

So far I made something like this:

```
pattern = '''<a class="x3-large" (.*)">(.*)</a>'''
```

But It doesn't do what I want, the first `(.*)` match all crap inside the link, But the second one the actual message that I want to get

Comment: Change the first `(.*)` into `(.*?)` and then just do `MatchObject.groups(1)`. you might want to reread the python [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) docs.

Comment: You can also just do `s.split('>',1)[1][:-4]` - try not to use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: If you want only last part of the string than why are you using `brackets` around the first `.*`. In regex `()` are used to capture a string you want. So if you want to extract only the last part try `pattern = '''<a class="x3-large" .*">(.*)</a>'''`. Also read about `greedy and non-greedy` regex quantifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of answering the question you should have asked instead ;^), yes, you should use BeautifulSoup [[link]](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or lxml or a real parser to handle HTML.  For example:

```
>>> s = '<a class="x3-large" href="_stuff--/SIG**morestuff" style="font-family: inherit;">Man learns not to give himself headaches using regex to deal with HTML</a>'
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.get_text()
u'Man learns not to give himself headaches using regex to deal with HTML'
```

Or if there are multiple texts to be captured:

```
>>> s = '<a class="test" href="ignore1">First sentence</a><a class="test" href="ignore1">Second sentence</a>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.find_all("a")
[<a class="test" href="ignore1">First sentence</a>, <a class="test" href="ignore1">Second sentence</a>]
>>> [a.get_text() for a in soup.find_all("a")]
[u'First sentence', u'Second sentence']
```

Or if you only want certain values of `class`:

```
>>> s = '<a class="test" href="ignore1">First sentence</a><a class="x3-large" href="ignore1">Second sentence</a>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.find_all("a", {"class": "x3-large"})
[<a class="x3-large" href="ignore1">Second sentence</a>]
```

Comment: But what if 'this' text will be different everytime, how would I get it?

Comment: Do you always want the text inside the "<a>" tag?

Comment: Yes, I only want the text that starts with <a class="x3-large" ...> Text that I want </a>

Answer (score 1):

Type `([^"]*)` instead of first `(.*)` and `([^<]*)` instead of second. Or use non greedy quantifiers like `(.*?)`.